# Bound from below the probability to go beyond a certain point in a zero mean random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk, upper-lower-bounds

Consider a random walk on a continous space, call it $W_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ where the $X_i$ are i.i.d. such that $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = 0$ and with finite variance. I would like to bound from below the following probability:
$$
P\Bigl(\bigcup_{n =1}^{\infty}W_n\geq\sqrt{n}\Bigr)\geq \mbox{ ??}
$$
It could also be written as:
$$
P\Bigl(\bigcup_{n =1}^{\infty}W_n\geq\sqrt{n}\Bigr) = P(\max_{n\geq 1}\frac{W_n}{\sqrt{n}}\geq 1)
$$
In particular, if I would have liked an upper bound for this quantity, then Kolmogorov's inequality would have solved my problem.

Unfortunately this is not the case and my literature search for an appropriate lower bound has failed. Thank you in advance for any help.

PS: if necessary I would add the expression of $W_n$ although I would prefer a general answer which simply use these general hypothesis.

Comment: Are you familiar with Kolmogorov's zero-one law?

Comment: @Michh not really, but actually I really think it could be the key to solve this problem. In fact I think that, in my case, this event occurs almost surely, and reading Wikipedia's page about the law you cited it seems to confirm my conjecture. Although it is not totally clear to me.. could you please explain me how it works? Or simply how to apply in this case.. thank you!

Comment: I was trying to use a generalized version of the Borel Cantelli's lemma, but unfortunately it doesn't help me. I should have pointed out that $\sum_{n= 1}^{\infty} P(W_n\geq\sqrt{n}) = \infty$, maybe it could help in some conditions.